# How to omit numerical values that have > or < signs

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has a column of numerical data which also contains values that have a > or < sign and these need to be excluded or filtered. I am not sure what type of data this is since the col indicates num but I can't seem to filter this data. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the class of that column is 'numeric'?  If there is a non-numeric element, the class would be either 'character' or 'factor' depending upon whether you used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or not while reading the dataset.  Can you post the dput of a small example dataset. i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(dataset)))` assuming that the there will be `>` or `<` signs within the first few rows.

Comment: Is it html? Like are the values similar to `"> 5 <"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either use `grep` to filter out the non-numeric elements in the specific column.

```
  df1[!grepl('[^0-9]', df1$Col1),]
```

Or use `as.numeric` to coerce the non-numeric elements to 'NA', and filter the rows with `is.na`.

```
  df1[!is.na(as.numeric(df1$Col1)),]
```

**NOTE:** There will be warning while coercing the non-numeric elements, but it is a friendly warning.  Also, if the column class is 'factor', convert to 'character' and then coerce to 'numeric' i.e. `as.numeric(as.character(df1$Col1))` or `as.numeric(levels(df1$Col1))[df1$Col1]`

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(Col1= c(1, 3, '>=3 ', 4, '<5'), Col2=rnorm(5), 
       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help !! Found that coercion resulted in too many hassles and could get the remaining columns back into numeric format. Finally resorted to saving the data frame as a csv file and then re-reading it in which I saw recommended elsewhere :)

Comment: Yes grepl was what I couldn't figure out. Need to spend some more time understanding the way it works. Still not sure why the not !grepl is required.

Comment: @SteveSidney  I was matching elements that are not numeric `[^0-9]`.  So, the grepl will give TRUE for all the elements that are non-numeric. Negating that we get the elements that are numeric, then subset it.